# How can I get the architecture of a '.a' file?

Tags: linux, elf

I have a .a file from which I want to get architecture information. Running `file myFile.a` results in `file.a: current ar archive`. How can I get more information on what architecture the file contains?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can also skip the `ar` command and use [readelf](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readelf+1), via something like:

`readelf -h <archive>.a | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'`

```
[00:32:15] /usr/lib $ readelf -h libxslt.a | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'
File: libxslt.a(attrvt.o)
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
File: libxslt.a(xslt.o)
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
... #Trimmed this, it goes on a bit
File: libxslt.a(transform.o)
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
File: libxslt.a(security.o)
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
[00:32:24] /usr/lib $
```

---

In case it's relevant, here's the other information that you can get from `readelf -h`. I just trimmed the above with `grep`, obviously:

```
File: libxslt.a(security.o)
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          2548 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         16
  Section header string table index: 13
```

That output is for *one* of the object files in `libxslt.a`, but it gives the same information for each file.

Comment: Recommend adding `Machine` to the list there.  That'll include info on the specific CPU the object files are made for, rather than just whether it's 32 or 64 bit or whatever.

Comment: @cHao: Yeah, I just thought of that, too. I'm doing another edit (and I added the entire output of `readelf -h`).

Comment: Trying to read a Darwin library on Linux produces this error: "readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start"

Answer (score 21):

Use

> lipo -info libExample.a

It will Who the architecture it build for. Other functions like otool or file doesn't give the exact answer and sometimes it to verbose to get the correct information.

Comment: lipo seems to be OS X specific.

Answer (score 15):

`objdump` is another option:

```
objdump -a file.a|grep 'file format'
```

Comment: Can not get architecture information (e.g. arm, x86, etc.) by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar

extract the object files from the archive and inspect them with file(1), nm(1), etc.

Comment: Is there any way to get architecture information without extracting its contents(at least without leaving any residue behind)?

Comment: @jer, actually, you can do it with either `readelf` or `objdump`.

Comment: @Matthew, Sorry, my mind was in OSX/iOS mode i'd been answering those questions all night, and didn't read the tag closely enough. Yeah, you are correct. Neither of those tools exist in osx's dev tools (one doesn't make sense on that platform anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using objdump instead of lipo. objdump provides detailed information than lipo.